# Python preset argument list

Tags: python, function, parameters

In my current project, I use a format of function very frequently.

```
def func(object, *args, **kwargs):
    #code goes here
```

I was wondering if it was possible to save some time and make it so that I can specify the `(object, *args, **kwargs)` part as an annotation or something, so the code needn't be repeated?

Comment: Potentially but how would you access those parameters inside the function if you refactor them away?

Comment: Refactor? I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

If you do this frequently, to save time, you can use the <s>force</s> power of modern IDEs.

For instance, in Pycharm, there is that [Smart Type Code Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html). Create a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/live-templates.html) and apply it to a Python context:

[image]

Then, whenever you type "genfunc", you'll get the autocomplete suggestion which would put the focus into the function name. After you finish typing the function, press ENTER and the focus would move to the function body:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have PyCharm XD, all I have is eclipse

Comment: @script8man not forcing you to Pycharm (it's entirely your choice), but there is a completely free community edition..